# Handle errors that cant be mapped to one frontend-page in a SOA

Tags: java, web-services, soa

I am currently working on a frontend-solution within a SOA, and I am running into troubles when saving domain-objects.

The backend gives me rather big domain-objects which are also saved as a whole. The frontend on the other side splits this data into multiple pages and sub-pages.

**Before I share my actual problem, I'd like to give some background information:**

Most tasks in our system are automated, using a process-engine, talking to webservices, and a rules-engine. The frontend is only needed when the input-data is incorrect so that a person needs to correct it. Input in the frontend is saved by the webservices and when the user thinks that everything is correct he passes the domain-object back to the process-engine.

**A simple example for the upcoming problem**

Domain-Object (which is basically the root-entity)

- Entity 1 which is displayed on page A (as well as some fields from the root-entity)
- Entity 2 displayed on page B

The **process identifies errors in each entity and marks them**. The user is given a task and the frontend loads the domain-object, displaying page A. The user corrects the fields and when he moves to page B the inputs should be saved so nothing of his work already done is lost.

**The Problem:**

the webservice responsible for saving the domain-object will throw an ValidationException because **Entity 2 still has errors**. You might be wondering how the incorrect data was saved in the first place? Well, the webservice exposes two services for saving, one called "automatic" and one called "manual". The operation automaticSave allowes invalid data, because the process-engine creates markers for each error that is returned. The manualSave currently doesnt allow errors.

**I am looking for advices how to adress this problem.**

I think this should be a rather common problem within a SOA. Correct me if I am wrong :-)

One way would be that the data in the frontend is only stored in the session and a user has to fix all errors before he can persist, but usability-wise I think thats not the best idea.

Another idea may be a partial validation on the backend, but this opens the door for incorrect data to be entered

My last idea was to pass the errors that were marked by the process-engine to manualSave so that the webservice knows *"hey, this field had errors before so I dont throw a ValidationException when only this is invalid"*

I am looking forward to your ideas.

**[Update]**
After the inital answers I've updated the structure of the domain object. It seems that this question could be extended to *"How to desgin a good webservice"* :-)

Comment: Just one question, are you able to change the webservices?

Comment: Yes, we could change the webservices, but our supervisor probably wont let us :-) From what I've learnt so far about webservices and SOA it seems that our design is not very service-like. A collegue just stated that its more like a service-wrapper for dao-operations.

Comment: but that is what a SOA service is most of the time, just a wrapper for some behind the scenes logic. As long as you service has a well defined role, is loosely coupled, is distributed and has a well define contract, then you kind of, have a SOA environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of issues here. The first issue I see is having two different operations on your web service that for the aggregate that you are trying to persist. By aggregate I mean saving the domain-object in one transaction (as a whole). Ultimately your issue is that you are not enforcing your invariants for the entity you are trying to auto save. There is no difference is auto save and manual save – you are still saving. In one operation you are saying it’s ok to leave out properties that would otherwise invalidate the entity, in the other you are actually enforcing the invariants saying it’s not a valid domain-object if you don’t include this data.

I can only assume that you are doing this to get partial persistence for your domain-object so you can accommodate the multi-page step through, for which you need the ID.  The auto save operation persists the partial domain-object and returns an ID, so you can perform your update operations (manual save) to make sure the entity is saved correctly and completely.

I think your initial idea to store the entity data in memory is a better approach. The only thing I would add to that is that the ID for the aggregate your service is persisting is created on the client and not by your backend system.

This allows you to pass from page to page and update as many models (Entity 1 and Entity 2) as you need to in order to persist a valid aggregate entity.  Each view model can have its own client side validation without impacting the other (you would still have the server side validation that runs as a backup).

When you are ready to save the domain-object (as a whole) simply map the view models (Entity 1 and 2) to it and save. You can then be certain that the domain-object has all invariants accounted for and should persist without error. Given that you have already created the ID on the client, there is no need for the round trip.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- (Minor) The names **automaticSave** and **manualSave** possibly leak a small amount of implementation details into the interface.  These names seem to reflect the behind-the-scenes processing, rather than the client's idea of what is happening.
- (Major) The same **manual save** is called twice from different contexts (page A and page B).  In both cases the client provides Entity1 and Entity2, indicating that 2 entities should be processed each time.  This is misleading & inefficient interface design.

I suggest the following:

1. (Minor) Rename **automaticSave** to either **backgroundSave** or **saveRequest**.  It does asynchronous processing (calls the process engine).
2. (Minor) Rename **manualSave** to **save**. It does synchronous processing (validation, data persistence, error reporting and return response from within the method).
3. (Major) Add two additional parameters to the **save** operation (and optionally, to the **backgroundSave** operation): **isEntity1Updated** & **isEntity2Updated** both of type boolean.  Only perform validation, data persistence and error reporting for each entity if the corresponding flag is true.

Advantages:

- Promotes flexibility, reusability & maintainability of your save operations - especially the validation of entities.  Interface supports synchronous & asynchronous processing of singular & combined entities.
- (Minor) Tightens up encapsulation by using client-specific terminology.
- Allows you to follow your desired user workflow - page A corrections, then save entity 1, then page B corrections, then save entity 2
- Good usability - page A corrections are not discarded just because of an error on page B (or lack of user follow-through to page B)
- Can still throw ValidationException during manual save - but only for the relevant entity that was just edited
- (Minor) Minimises network traffic - if an entity is not updated a null can be passed instead of passing a non-updated entity which will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Well, books have been written about how to design a good SOA so I won't go into it here.  Seems you're in a "get it done" mode, in which case I'd suggest that when the user submits page A, the object is saved using "automaticSave" because you are still allowing errors.  Only when the user's task is completed would you use "manualSave".  I wouldn't design a system this way but if stuck with one this seems the most reasonable way to proceed, since this matches the expectations of the service client with the contract of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you but I need to get a few more details.

> The frontend is only needed when the input-data is incorrect so that a person needs to correct it. Input in the frontend is saved by the webservices and when the user thinks that everything is correct he passes the domain-object back to the process-engine.

What do you mean by domain object? The backend cannot return any domain object because if the system is properly layered the domain object stays in the Domain Layer, and you're talking to the API Layer/Service Layer, so at the most what you're getting is a representation of the domain object. It might look the same to you, but the semantics are completely different.

So when you get the object that represents a domain object, you talk about entity 1 and entity 2, but what are they? And what protocol is being (REST, SOAP)?

Also can you just provide us with the methods of the webservices, you're making a reference to services that validate and others that save, so I just want to make sure I understand everything.

> One way would be that the data in the frontend is only stored in the session and a user has to fix all errors before he can persist, but usability-wise I think thats not the best idea.

And so far based on your input this is the only way, but don´t forget that you always have two stages of validation, in the front-end and again in the Domain.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Following my reply:

> In order to efficiently use a SOA, the architecture must meet the following requirements: Interoperability among different systems and programming languages that provides the basis for integration between applications on different platforms through a communication protocol. One example of such communication depends on the concept of messages. Using messages across defined message channels decreases the complexity of the end application, thereby allowing the developer of the application to focus on true application functionality instead of the intricate needs of a communication protocol.
>   Desire to create a federation of resources. Establish and maintain data flow to a federated database system. This allows new functionality developed to reference a common business format for each data element

In fairnesss web services that call webservices are SOA.

Comment: My definition of domain-object is obviously not right. As I've updated in the question: the domain-object in this particular case is the root-entity, which has some relations to other entities which are also included. Even worse, in some cases you add another entity to a list of something and save but the new entity hasnt been added because for adding relations the webservice exposes additional methods that do just add (adding a new object to the root-entity).